# Передача хеша параметров в модель

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Столкнулся с некоторой трудностью. `ruby v 2.3.0p0`, `Rails 4.2.5.1`.

Имеется модель товара `Item.rb`

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0, allow_nil: true }
  validates :name, :description, presence: true

end
```

Данная модель принимает параметры, которые предопределены в контроллере `ItemsController`.

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    Item.new(item_params)
  end

  def new

  end

  def index
    @items = Item.all
    render text: @items.map { |i|  "#{i.name}: #{i.price} "}.join("<br>")
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :price, :real, :weight, :description)
  end

end
```

По условию, мне нужно, чтобы хеш параметров, передаваемый через `GET` запрос:

```
http://localhost:3000/items/new?name=car1&price=50000&real=1&weigth=102&description=newcar
```

в действие `new (get "items/new" => "items#new" - маршрут routes.rb)` создавал валидный экземпляр объекта класса `Item` и записывал его в базу данных с последующим выводом его:

```
p @item
render text: "Item created: #{@item.id}: #{@item.name}- #{!@item.new_record?}"
```

Вот тут у меня возникла некая трудность. Никак не могу въехать, как это сделать рабочим. Вот мои попытки:

```
@item = Item.create(params[:item])
@item = Item.create(params[:item_params]
```

И еще некоторые, но абсурдные даже с моей точки зрения.

Во всех моих попытках создавался либо пустой экземпляр класса `Item`, либо выводилась ошибка что параметр `:item` в `item_params` не может быть пустым. Два дня пытался вразумить, как это реализовать.

Comment: Что в роутах, касательно `Item`?

Comment: В роутах только это: 

  get "items" => "items#index"

  get "items/new" => "items#new"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экшен будет таким:

```
def new
  @item = Item.create(item_params)
end
```

Метод, возвращающий из всех переданных параметров только нужные для создания:

```
def item_params
  params.permit(:name, :price, :real, :weight, :description)
end
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек! Совсем извел меня этот вопрос. А все оказалось проще, чем я предполагал. Искал просто не там. Добра тебе!